# Are there any SSH / Telnet clients for Windows that support tabs?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, telnet

I currently use putty for SSH and Telnet on Windows. But the lack of tab support in Putty makes it difficult for me to keep multiple windows open at once (up 10 at a time).

Does anyone know anything that can provide a tabbed interface? Someone had told me about Putty Connection Manager. But that project seems to be discontinued as the website is no longer available.

Has anyone continued that project or is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

[MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) have tab system and some nice tools for managing server

Answer (score 1):

Try [Terminals](https://terminals.codeplex.com/), which is a nice Opensource tool. It support SSH and tabs.

Comment: That is a really nice tool. I tested it for SSH and it does well. But I find myself managing Telnet more and PuttyCM allows for auto login macros. Can terminals do that?

Comment: I don't know. Test it and if it doesn't support it, create a workitem on the codeplex site.